# getting array from object from api and diplay iteratively

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an array of object json encoded from an api and i would like to display an the each row of objects on a new line

```
  var me3 = jsondata["message"];

    for (var i = 1; i < me3.length; i++)

      me3.forEach((element) => print(element));

    Set<String> set = Set.from(me3);
    set.forEach((element) => premiumList
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Company : $element[1]", propertyLocation:"SSN : 3001245" )));
```

The aim is to display each record on a new property sheet and display the the tradename value in each row ..

Comment: Can Add your response object ?

Comment: @AR {"tradenam1e":"data ","ssn1":"data","email1":"email"}

Answer (score 0):

Using StringBuffer we print

```
  var responseFromAPI = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
  String _errorMessage = "";
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

  for (String line in responseFromAPI) {
    sb.write(line + "\n");
  }
  _errorMessage = sb.toString();
  print(_errorMessage);
```